# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IState':

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import ChartContainer from "./Chart/ChartContainer";
import "./App.css";

function App() {

  return <ChartContainer />;
}

export default App;
```

The chartcontainer component has a state interface, why is it expecting props?

```
// @ts-ignore
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import Canvas from "./Canvas"
import { convertData } from "./Helpers"
type IState = {
  data: unknown;
  prevMonthStam: number;
}

const ChartContainer: React.FunctionComponent<IState> = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<unknown>([])
  const [prevMonthStamp, setPrevMonthStamp] = React.useState<number>()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    var d: any = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 2);
    d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPrevMonthStamp((d / 1000 | 0) * 1000); //timestamp of a month ago
  }, [])


  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1d'
    }).then(res => {
      if (prevMonthStamp) {
        setData(res.data.filter((i: number[]) => i[0] >= prevMonthStamp))
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }, [prevMonthStamp])


  if (Array.isArray(data) && data?.length > 0) {
    return (
      <Canvas data={convertData(data)} />
    );
  } else {
    return null
  }

}
export default ChartContainer;
```

How to differentiate between props and state in this case for the interface?
This wont work either and im defining an empty props interface, and its still asking the same

Point it used to work this way until i restarted the ide

```
type IState = {
  data: unknown;
  prevMonthStam: number;
}

type IProps = {
}

const ChartContainer: React.FunctionComponent<IState & IProps>
```

Comment: `const ChartContainer: React.FunctionComponent<IState> = () =>` you are saying that `ChartContainer` is of type of `React.FunctionComponent` and to it it WILL pass in props that are defined by `IState` type. Right now your component receives 0 props as defined here `= () =>`. A simple `= (props) =>` should solve it. But why are you setting up a type for props when you dont even use the props `data` nor `prevMonthStam`? also, the `IProps` or `IState` is just a name, it means nothing. and its not `state` or `props`, its basically a structure of your component properties

Comment: @Lith well I do understand that I have no props. But I have two states. Shouldnt those be defined in an interface too? Thats what im trying to do.
Cant I define a interface for the props, and another one for the state?

Comment: Types, or interfaces, are not used for that. ill post an answer shortly trying to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from `const ChartContainer: React.FunctionComponent<IState> = () =>`as it seems you do not understand what types are. Here you define a constant named `ChartContainer` and his type is `React.FunctionComponent`. As a react component it himself can have properties and you defined those with `IState`. This is NOT a state or a structure of your variables. Its a structure, or a definition, of what properties can, or have to, be passed to a component via properties whenever initializing it.

In this case tou need to do `const ChartContainer: React.FunctionComponent<IState> = (props) =>` to solve the error. But its far from perfect.

The way you setting up now means the `prevMonthStamp` and `data` will come from a parent component via, for exmaple, `<ChartContainer data={... some data...} prevMonthStamp={...some data...} />`. But in your case you create both variables inside the component and do not use the outside properties passed from a parent

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState<unknown>([])
const [prevMonthStamp, setPrevMonthStamp] = React.useState<number>()
```

Since you dont even need properties, you should just leave it blank `const ChartContainer: React.FunctionComponent = () =>`

Also, would suggest using `const ChartContainer: React.FC = () =>` instead. Less writing yet same outcome.

And to pass a property structure `const ChartContainer: React.FC<...your type...> = () =>`

tl;dr

Types can be named whatever you want and are just a definition, or a structure, of your passing outside variables as properties to component on initialization NOT a structure of your component states, variables or whatever.

p.s. types can also be used for variables like so

```
type user = {
  name: string
  surname: string
}
```

and then somewhere in the code

```
const user: user = {name: "Lith", surname: "Lithium"}
```

Comment: Okey, so the tldr is use interface only for props.